# Redirect from root page to /de/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, typo3

i have a typo3 site that has all urls in the form of www.mysite.com/de/page/xyz/..
the problem is that the root of the page ( / ) shows the same content as www.mysite.com/de/ which is in my opinion bad because of duplicate content. somehow i cannot manage to correctly redirect people accessing www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/de/. i am always getting a redirection loop or it somehow redirects to /de/index.php which generates a 404 by typo3.

what is the correct way to set this kind of redirect when using the provided .htaccess file from typo3 and the realurl extension? (it is an old site runing typo3 4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
# First condition: Only match host example.com with or without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$

# Second condition: Only match if Request URI is /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

# If both conditions match, redirect to http://www.example.com/en/ (Status code 301)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/en/ [R=301,L]
```

Also pay attention to where you put this rewrite rule. If you have other rewrite rules before this one, it maybe doesn't get executed if another rule matches.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I actually had something similar with a little mistake and some other rules were bevor this.